# Log only errors in IIS

Tags: logging, iis-7.5

We are running some pretty large sites with 100k+ pageviews per day. We are not looking into a way to customize the logging a bit.

We did switch from IIS 6 to IIS 7.5 recently and we haven't found anyway to set the verbosity level. In IIS 6 we could set

- OFF
- FATAL
- ERROR
- WARN
- INFO
- DEBUG
- ALL

We are usually only interested in the ERROR and FATAL log lines.

Is there a way to achieve this in IIS 7.5 or do we have to change approach?
Is there possibly any tools that may run a couple of times a day that refines the logs sorting out what we are interested of?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about the verbosity level of IIS logs? IIS logging does not use verbosity and what you described is something for log4net or a similar logging framework.

Comment: Here is an example from IIS 6. http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/d87ac473-eddb-4f7e-9a91-ce9f168b5635.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: That link refers to a completely different logging/tracing system (similar to ETW, and only used for debugging or troubleshooting). It is never a good idea to leave it running for a long time. Why do you want to touch this piece of IIS?